# Mapkit :How to add annotation on MKLocalSearch results placemarks?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, objective-c-blocks, mkannotation

Basically I need a way to put annotation on all the "Walmarts" that search request picks up. I am not using interface builder, I am just using code for this app.

```
MKMapView * map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:
                   CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
map.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:map];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"Walmart";
request.region = map.region;
```

Comment: Your initialization also needs altering - follow what XCode comments say - all mapview initialization must happen after [super viewDidLoad].

Comment: @moomoo - FYI, I've updated my answer for a refinement if working on slow network, whereby it cancels a prior search (if any still in progress) before initiating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest simply creating the mapview in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MKMapView * map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    map.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:map];
}
```

But when the user moves the map, look for Walmarts and add the annotations:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // if on slow network, it's useful to keep track of the previous
    // search, and cancel it if it still exists

    [self.previousSearch cancel];

    // create new search request

    MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"Walmart";
    request.region = mapView.region;

    // initiate new search

    MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSMutableArray *annotations = [NSMutableArray array];

        [response.mapItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MKMapItem *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            // if we already have an annotation for this MKMapItem,
            // just return because you don't have to add it again

            for (id<MKAnnotation>annotation in mapView.annotations)
            {
                if (annotation.coordinate.latitude == item.placemark.coordinate.latitude &&
                    annotation.coordinate.longitude == item.placemark.coordinate.longitude)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }

            // otherwise, add it to our list of new annotations
            // ideally, I'd suggest a custom annotation or MKPinAnnotation, but I want to keep this example simple

            [annotations addObject:item.placemark];
        }];

        [mapView addAnnotations:annotations];
    }];

    // update our "previous" search, so we can cancel it if necessary

    self.previousSearch = localSearch;
}
```

Clearly, this code sample assumes that you have a `weak` property for the previous search operation. (This is not, strictly speaking, necessary, but may give you better performance if browsing around on a map when you have a slow Internet connection.) Anyway, that property would be defined as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) MKLocalSearch *previousSearch;
```

---

There are other possible refinements (e.g. `UIActivityIndicatorView` or network activity indicator if search is in progress, perhaps remove annotations that are not within the map's current region, etc.), but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach:

```
MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[self.localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {

if(error)
{
        NSLog(@"localSearch startWithCompletionHandlerFailed!  Error: %@", error);
        return;
} 
else 
{
        for(MKMapItem *mapItem in response.mapItems)
        {
             MKPinAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPinAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate: mapItem.placemark.location.coordinate];
             [map addAnnotation:annotation];
             NSLog(@"Name for result: = %@", mapItem.name);
        }
}}];
```